# What is the difference between these expressions in asp.net mvc views"<%: %>", "<%= %>"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

<%= %> I know that this means Response.Write but what is the meaning of ":" sign?

Comment: [New <%: %> Syntax for HTML Encoding Output in ASP.NET 4 (and ASP.NET MVC 2)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`<%:%>` is like `<%=Server.HtmlEncode()%>`, and was introduced in ASP.NET 4.0. In addition to outputting, it also HtmlEncodes the output, to avoid most simple cases of [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

The whole thing is a shortcut to:

```
<script language="vbscript" runat="server">
    Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode()))
</script>
```